# Need help determining encoding of the text

Tags: character-encoding

This is cyrillic text of unknown encoding displayed in windows-1251. Pretty sure it's not UTF8, ISO8859-5 or KOI8. I couldn't determine the actual encoding, does anyone has a clue?

`ГђВџГђВѕГђВ»ГђВЅГ‘В‹ГђВ№ ГђВєГђВ°ГђВґГ‘ВЂ`

Comment: There’s an obvious pattern ГxВy here, suggesting that the data is not simply Cyrillic text in some encoding but somehow distorted text, possibly the result is some incorrect code conversions. Please disclose your information of where the text might come from (technically and otherwise).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: There could be more than 1 conversion involved, I don't know. I have updated the question with another string. The original text for it is "Полный кадр" (without quotes). Also, I see no ГxВy in my question so I think it didn't even come across to you as it should have...

Comment: Show the binary/hex values of the bytes, not the values in some unknown interpretation. Generally though, if you don't know, just try to open it as every possible encoding until you find the right one. Also: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: It does not help to just change the string; rather, that’s confusing. And the data, as posted here, clearly has a repeating pattern consisting of U+0413 CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER GHE “Г” followed by a character followed by U+0412 CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER VE “В” followed by a character, i.e. a ГxВy pattern. The new data just as U+0060 GRAVE ACCENT “`” at the start and U+0027 APOSTROPHE “'” at the end, possibly intended to stand as quotation marks around the actual data, possibly part of it.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: sorry, I needed to change the data when I realized I can't give the original for it. And the apostrophe was my mistake, fixed.

Comment: Please don't close this, I have cracked the case. @VioletGiraffe what programming language should I use in my answer?

Comment: Looks like each Cyrillic letter got converted to four bytes and the space remained invariant. This must be the result of some processing, not just simple code conversion.

Comment: @Esailija: I know C++ and a bit of Java, if you use something remotely similar I should be able to comprehend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the original string has first been encoded as utf8, then interpreted in iso-8859-1 and then the result again encoded as utf-8. Solution given in java. Assumes you have the raw byte access, otherwise more code is required to get them.

```java
//The underlying bytes are these, based on the characters being displayed in windows-1251

byte[] rawBytes = {(byte)0xc3,(byte)0x90,(byte)0xc2,(byte)0x9f,(byte)0xc3,(byte)0x90,(byte)0xc2,
                    (byte)0xbe,(byte)0xc3,(byte)0x90,(byte)0xc2,(byte)0xbb,(byte)0xc3,(byte)0x90,
                    (byte)0xc2,(byte)0xbd,(byte)0xc3,(byte)0x91,(byte)0xc2,(byte)0x8b,(byte)0xc3,
                    (byte)0x90,(byte)0xc2,(byte)0xb9,(byte)0x20,(byte)0xc3,(byte)0x90,(byte)0xc2,
                    (byte)0xba,(byte)0xc3,(byte)0x90,(byte)0xc2,(byte)0xb0,(byte)0xc3,(byte)0x90,
                    (byte)0xc2,(byte)0xb4,(byte)0xc3,(byte)0x91,(byte)0xc2,(byte)0x80};

//alternatively this will work just as well:
//Charset windows1251 = Charset.forName("Windows-1251");
//byte[] rawBytes = windows1251.encode("ГђВџГђВѕГђВ»ГђВЅГ‘В‹ГђВ№ ГђВєГђВ°ГђВґГ‘ВЂ").array();

Charset utf8 = Charset.forName("utf-8");
String asUTF8 = utf8.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(rawBytes)).toString();

//Intermediate step required to convert the intermediate string
//to byte[] again. Iso-8859-1 is used because it maps 256 first 
//unicode points exactly to byte values of 0-255

Charset iso88591 = Charset.forName( "ISO-8859-1");
byte[] bytes = iso88591.encode(asUTF8).array();

String finalResult = utf8.decode( ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes)).toString();
System.out.println(finalResult);
//Полный кадр
```

Comment: What does "double encoded utf-8" mean? I've never heard of it.

Comment: @ArtB It means a string is first converted to utf8 bytes, then the bytes are again encoded in utf8 resulting in each original utf8 byte being encoded in utf8

Comment: Analyzing the pattern showed fully valid utf8 bytes, so I decoded it as utf8, it showed again a pattern of valid utf8, so I decoded the result again as utf-8 and `Полный кадр` is shown :P

Comment: Ah, double-encoding should have no effect on the ANSI-subset of UTF-8 used by English right? Probably why it doesn't get detected until later. (Could this be an argument for using BOM even with utf-8?)

Comment: @ArtB You mean ASCII subset (<128)? Yes, if the original string is just ASCII characters then double encoding has no effect. Anyway, you have to go out of your way to double encode as utf8, I mean just look at the code to decode it. The code that originally made this string is a huge wtf. I don't think BOM helps there.

Comment: @ArtB although I suppose in PHP it's easily possible due to how misleading the function `utf8_encode` is, all you need to do to achieve it in php is to `utf8_encode($utf8_string)` where `$utf8_string` is already in utf-8. The `utf8_encode` doesn't check if it's already utf-8 but assumes it's ISO-8859-1.

Comment: "Double encoding" still doesn't make a whole lot of sense. You can only ever *convert* encodings correctly or incorrectly, never "encode twice". Do you mean that a UTF-8 encoded string was converted "from Latin1" to UTF-8? I.e. the bytes in the UTF-8 encoded string were interpreted as Latin1 and encoded as UTF-8? In that case simply reversing that should do the trick, i.e. convert the string from UTF-8 to Latin1, then interpret the "Latin1 bytes" as UTF-8.

Comment: @deceze that's just an implementation detail cos of java, if you were able to get `byte[]` result from `charset.decode`, then I wouldn't need ISO-8859-1 at all. It would just be `String finalResult = utf8.decode(utf8.decodeAsBytes(rawBytes))` ISO-8859-1 is used for [its binary string property](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13764305/995876).

Comment: Well, you're probably doing the correct thing, just the explanation of "encoded twice" doesn't sit right with me. :)

Comment: @deceze Well, if you know php, it can easily happen with this: (Save file in UTF-8): `<?php header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"); $utf8 = "ö"; echo utf8_encode($utf8);` That means encoding a string already in utf-8 as utf-8, hence double encoded utf-8 :P

Comment: Yeah, but again, that's no "double encode", it's *incorrectly convert from Latin1 to UTF-8.* "Encoding" is when you write the byte sequence for "the letter A", "decoding" is when you decode `x41` to "the letter A". Converting bytes to other bytes is a *conversion*. `</pedantism>` :P

Comment: @deceze Yeah I guess you're right, you should still upvote; P