# Russian utf-8 shows special characters? (PHP)

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I displayed some Russian words on `HTML` and it showed like following.

> ГђВџГђВѕГђВ»ГђВЅГ‘В‹ГђВ№ ГђВєГђВ°ГђВґГ‘ВЂ

The result is:

> Полный кадр

I tried to convert the original string to `UTF8` and displayed in `HTML`. I showed like above.

Some information:

> store field collation: latin1_swedish_ci

The sql result is :

> ÐÐ¾Ð»Ð½ÑÐ¹ ÐºÐ°Ð´Ñ

I queried the database and get the value. And then convert to `utf8`:

```
mb_convert_encoding($value, 'utf-8', 'windows-1251');
```

Could you please take a look at this link. Someone fixed it:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765242/need-help-determining-encoding-of-the-text
```

**The problem is I'm rebuilding a website. Some data is from old website. And I cannot input it manually because It's a lot. So I wrote a php script to get data from the old website and inserted to my new website. The old website display russian in HTML perfectly. But I didn't code it, and I cannot see his code.
I already check the data between old table and new table. It's the same.**

Comment: try to build on sql fiddle

Comment: Are the characters entities or the actual character? Latin1 doesn't support russian characters.

"The major drawback of using Latin-1 is that it has only 256 possible characters, and therefore has no way of effectively representing characters in languages whose alphabets differ significantly from English (this includes languages like Russian, Greek, Hebrew, Arabic, almost all Asian languages and just about every language ever invented by humans)."
https://www.bluebox.net/insight/blog-article/getting-out-of-mysql-character-set-hell

You won't be able to convert what isn't there, e.g. the char.

Comment: Someone fixed here by another langauge , not PHP. 
And I cannot find some functions from PHP likes the code there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765242/need-help-determining-encoding-of-the-text

Comment: I'm sorry, but without knowledge of at least either what the actual bytes are, and/or what text these bytes is supposed to display as, there are simply too many variables. Please update your question with this information.

Comment: I edited. Please help me.

Comment: Do you generally have problems to support Russian in your app? Then look at the duplicate. Or do you already have a ton of irreproducible data which is corrupted using the wrong charset and you're trying to rescue it? Then we do indeed need more information. Read [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) and [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) and maybe that'll give you enough information to figure it out yourself.

Comment: I think I had the same problem as yours.  I inherited a system where MySQL fields show something like ÐÐ¾Ð»Ð½ÑÐ¹ ÐºÐ°Ð´Ñ but the HTML output is correctly in Russian/Cyrillic.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407834/mysql-convert-latin1-characters-on-a-utf8-table-into-utf8 this might answer your problem as it had mine.  Pls don't downvote if it doesnt answer your question as I was also looking for the answer myself.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should change collation for your table to e.g. `utf8_unicode_ci`, or `koir...` for Russian, so you can get the right result. `latin_swedish` does not support Cyrillic characters.

Comment: He/she probably needs to do charset and collation, presuming charset is latin1 as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341273/what-does-character-set-and-collation-mean-exactly

Comment: Thanks for your help. But It is the same as before.

Comment: Write something new to the table and see if it comes out as you expect. If not please post what you inputted and what it came out as.

Comment: try dropping db/table, recreate tables with unicode charset and collation, and test-run your scrapping script again.